# what cloud provider can be use to move GCP data to S3 securely? That can be schedule

Tags: migration

I tried AWS Datasync installed the agent using an instance, but its public expose to the internet, any other option for this to work?

I tried AWS Datasync installing agent in an ec2. but it didn't work with private subnet to connect with GCP.